# Base64 conversion with UIImage: NSData is not nil, but UIImage is nil

Tags: ios, swift, string, null, uiimage

I am currently converting a user-picked `UIImage` to a base64 string using the below method, but when I go to convert that back into an image using the below method, I can get the `NSData`, but I can't convert that into a `UIImage`.  Any thoughts? I have already tried using both PNG and JPEG methods for the `UIImage`, and neither worked if that adds any detail.

Thanks,

Jacob

Encoding Code:

```
 var base64 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profileView.image!))!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

Decoding Code:

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: String(user?.photoURL), options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
let decodedimage = UIImage(data: decodedData!) //this decoded image is nil
```

Comment: What is `user?.photoURL` ?

Comment: You want to convert `NSData` to `UIImage`? Is that right?

Comment: I'd look at `String(user?.photoURL)`, as it probably includes some "Optional(...)" syntactic noise...

Comment: @MidhunMP  It's from Firebase: that's how I am getting my current user's base64 String that contains their profile picture

Comment: @Rob  Okay, will do

Comment: @Rob That did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with code:

```
let image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"your_image")!
let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
```

**Encoding:**

```
let base64:String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

**Decoding**

```
let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)!
```

**Here is the code to convert `NSData` to `UIImage`**

```
let image: UIImage = UIImage(data:dataDecoded,scale:1.0)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: THANK YOU! In combination with @Rob's answer, I was able to get it work!